# Java batch application and idle thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, batch-file, concurrency

I have java application processing batch files, the service is bursty, i get many or few files and then no processing for some time, sometimes for hours. I have a thread pool to process batch file requests in parallel. I observe that first procesing after the idle time is slow and then it picks up the speed. Apllication is up for days, warmed up, but there is no consistent response time after application inactivity. Do threads really become 'cold' after idle time? if so, what's the way to keep application warmed up during inactivity time?

Here is my ThreadPoolTaskExecutor initialization:

```
final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2000);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(250);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix(prefix);
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(20);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(wait);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two type of threads in `ThreadPoolExecutor` : core and non-core.
Core threads are always active and can't be terminated by default. It's only possible to terminate them using `allowCoreThreadTimeOut`. In contrast non-core threads are terminated if they are idle longer than `keepAliveTime`. Here is comprehensive description of [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor-int-int-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue-) configuration parameters. So only core threads can keep pool warm and give you a consistent response time. `ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool` with give number of core threads seems like a suitable thread pool configuration for your case. Trade-off is a constant usage of OS resources for keeping threads active.

Comment: Nikita, thanks for the reply. I do set executor.setCorePoolSize(100) in my ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. And still see slow processing after an application inactivity.

Comment: Are you sure that thread pool is an issue? Can it be internal pools and caches of third-party frameworks for example?

Comment: After an idle time I run 100K file, first run 3x longer than next 3 runs. I wouldn't think cache gets clear during inactivity. Could compiler do some sort of memory 'optimization' for inactive application?

Comment: @user3140656: the CPU, the harddrive and even your entire computer can go into a powersave mode when idle.

Comment: Holger, my app is running on aws cloud, there are system processes running, including salt.